# Subjects vs Publish

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I've been playing with Rx for the last day or so and one thing that still doesn't quite make sense to me is Subject.

When would I use this class directly?

It seems to me that I'd be more likely to expose an IObservable and use the Publish method to create an IConnectableObservable. I then have the option of using RefCount to convert back to an IObservable that monitors its subscriber.

I'm sure I'm missing something here. If you have any insight I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that exposing Subject directly is unlikely to be what you want.  Usually, you would use a Subject internally and expose it as an IObservable.  One example of when you might do this is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980014).

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Rx as well, but I've used them for classes that have hot observables. ie.

```
class NumberMonitor
{
  Subject<double> _source = new Subject<double>();
  public IObservable<double> NumberStream {get {return _source.AsObservable; } }

  void OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    _source.OnNext(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep - a Subject is the most straightforward IObservable, it's just one you signal manually like you're doing above

Answer (score 0):

I've used AsyncSubject for some sort of completion flags internally in a ViewModel class as a quick fix, I would say they looked way cleaner than doing Observable.Create instead.